# Versioning the node hierarchy in JCR?

Tags: version-control, hierarchy, jcr

I know that individual nodes can be versioned in JCR repositories. But what if I have documents that are comprised of a hierarchy of small individual snippets, aliases to nodes in larger snippet pool. I'd like to take a snapshot of all the nodes in a document and share information of the current state of the hierarchy among all clients that are editing the document. Is that possible with JCR and can you give me some pointers on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (and quite easy) to version a subgraph in its entirety. The node at the top of the subgraph should have the `jcr:versionable` mixin, either explicitly or implicitly via a supertype of the node's primary type or mixin types. No other node in the subgraph needs to be marked as versionable; in fact, it's far easier if none of them do have it.

By default, all "on parent versioning" behavior of property definitions and child node definitions are `COPY`, which will work perfectly.

Then, simply get the `VersionManager` for the JCR `Session` (via the session's workspace), and check in the node:

```
javax.jcr.Node subgraphRoot = ...
javax.jcr.VersionManager vmgr = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
vmgr.checkin(subgraphRoot.getPath());
```

Checking it out to modify it is just as simple:

```
vmgr.checkout(subgraphRoot.getPath());
```